# PySpark error when trying to execute compute

Tags: pyspark

Working on with Pyspark.  Received this code error

```
  from pyspark.sql import functions as F # Chris Kehl 1/16/24
  from transforms.api import transform_df, Input, Output

@transform_df(
    Output("/Users/1103595297/transform_readings"),
    df_n=Input("/transform/datasets/transform_notications"),
    df_q=Input("/clean/qmel"),
    imrg=Input("/clean/imrg"),
    imptt=Input("/clean/imptt")
)

###########################################################################
# Date: Created: 01/2/2024 
# Author: Chris Kehl
# Purpose: SAP Readings from the Notifications
# Return Type: Return dataframe
###########################################################################
def compute(df_n, df_q, imrg, imptt):
    df_n = df_n.select("notification_number",
                       "internal_equipment_number",
                        "family",
                        "serial_number",
                        "notification_type",
                        "fault_description_qmtxt",
                        "priority_type_artpr",
                        "priority_priok",
                        "date_of_notification_qmdat",
                        "required_start_date_strmn",
                        "date_for_compeletion_of_notification_qmdmb")
    df_q = df_q.select("notification_no_qmnum",
                       "object_number_for_status_management_objnr")
    df_n = df_n.join(df_q,
                     df_n.notification_number == df_q.notification_no_qmnum,
                     'left')
    df_n = df_n.drop('notification_number_qmnum')
    imrg = imrg.select("measurement_document_mdocm",
                       "measuring_point_point",
                       "date_of_the_measurement_idate",
                       "indicator_counter_reading_document_cntrg",
                       "measurement_document_text_mdtxt",
                       "deletion_flag_for_1_level_deletion_logic_lvorm",
                       "origin_indicator_gener",
                       "object_number_of_order_woobj",
                       "measurement_reading_total_counter_reading_in_si_unit_readg",
                       "measurement_reading_in_unit_of_entry_recdv",
                       "unit_of_measurement_for_document_entry_recdu",
                       "counter_reading_difference_in_si_unit_cdiff",
                       "reversal_indicator_cancl")
    imrg = imrg.filter(F.col("origin_indicator_gener") == "A")
    df_n = df_n.join(imrg,
                     df.n.object_number_for_status_management_objnr == imrg.object_number_of_order_woobj, 
                     how="inner")
    return df_n
```

Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "compute", line 1, in 
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transforms/api/_transform.py", line 216, in **call**
return self._compute_func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: compute() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'df_n', 'df_q', and 'imptt'